# Align heading to the top with flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having three flexboxes next to each other. They all look identical: A picture, a heading and some text. For some reason, the text aligns to the bottom, if one of the headings becomes too long and wraps.

```
<div class="flex" data-bind="foreach:  { data: menuItems }">
    <div class="leBorderContainer" data-bind="click: $data.clickEvent">
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: $data.imageUrl}" src="img/btn/fragezeichen.svg">
        <h2 data-bind="text: $data.header">Dokumentenzentrum</h2>
        <section data-bind="template: { nodes: $($data.content), data: $root }"><p>Hier finden Sie alle wichtigen Dokumente, Formulare und Publikationen von Lechner.</p></section>
    </div>

    <div class="leBorderContainer" data-bind="click: $data.clickEvent">
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: $data.imageUrl}" src="img/btn/suche.svg">
        <h2 data-bind="text: $data.header">Montage- und Pflegeanleitungen</h2>
        <section data-bind="template: { nodes: $($data.content), data: $root }"><p>Klicken Sie hier, um alle unsere Montage- und Pflegeanleitungen auf einen Blick zu finden. Sie werden auf unsere Homepage weitergeleitet.</p></section>
    </div>

    <div class="leBorderContainer" data-bind="click: $data.clickEvent">
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: $data.imageUrl}" src="img/btn/suche.svg">
        <h2 data-bind="text: $data.header">Broschüren und Kataloge</h2>
        <section data-bind="template: { nodes: $($data.content), data: $root }"><p>Finden Sie hier eine Übersicht aller unserer Broschüren und Kataloge. Sie werden auf unsere Homepage weitergeleitet.</p></section>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's one div with the fullScreenMenu class around that. Here's my CSS:

```
.fullScreenMenu img:first-child {
    position: relative;
    width: 96px;
    left: -42px;
    top: -42px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -32px;
    margin-bottom: -54px;
}

.fullScreenMenu h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.fullScreenMenu h2 {
    padding-top: 12px;
    font-weight: 500;
    align-content:flex-start; /* this doesn't help */
}

.fullScreenMenu p:first-of-type {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fullScreenMenu .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

    .fullScreenMenu .flex > div {
        max-width: 250px;
        transition: background-color .5s;
        margin-left: 48px;
    }

        .fullScreenMenu .flex > div:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #ffdd00;
        }

        .fullScreenMenu .flex > div ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 1.2em;
            text-indent: -1.2em;
        }


            .fullScreenMenu .flex > div ul li:before {
                content: "➠";
                display: block;
                float: left;
                width: 1.2em;
            }
```

Does anybody have an idea, how I can make the h2 text align to the top in multiline scenarios? Right now, the "Dokumentenzentrum" text starts in the second line, while "Montage- und Pflegeanleitungen" as well as "Broschüren und Kataloge" are both two-lined.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you explain your problem? what do you want to achieve

Comment: Consider posting a live demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net) and/or illustration of the problem.